# Choosing whether to include PDF or PNG in PDFLaTeX

Tags: graphics, pdftex, png

Can I tell `graphicx` somehow which graphic format to choose when I omit the file extension in `includegraphics` and both a PDF and a PNG version of the same image exist? The reason is that I have some very large PDF vector graphics (in terms of file size/drawing primitives) that take a pretty long time to load each time I view the document. I would like to convert them to PNGs while working on the document and only use the PDF versions in the final document. Therefore, a global option that I can switch in the end would be great.

An additional plus would be to do the conversion to PNG on the fly during the LaTeX run if there is a PDF that has not been converted to PNG yet, if a tool for that exists. (I know how to use `convert`, but not how to include it automatically in LaTeX.)

Comment: A cheap solution is to load `graphicx` with the `draft` option, that avoids the inclusion of the graphic files, while setting a box with the correct dimensions.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to skip the inclusion of these images entirely, I want to include a different (rasterized) version.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

The order of preference when files with the same name and different extensions is

```
.png .pdf .jpg .mps .jpeg .jbig2 .jb2 .PNG .PDF .JPG .JPEG .JBIG2 .JB2
```

which is stored in the macro `\Gin@extensions`. So if you have both `image.png` and `image.pdf`, `pdflatex` will load the former.

If you are mixing case in extensions, then

```
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{%
    .png,.PNG,%
    .pdf,.PDF,%
    .jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2}
```

will ensure that PNG are always preferred over PDF files. For the final version it will be sufficient to switch the two lines.

A handier way, suggested by Heiko Oberdiek, is to use the package `grfext`:

```
\usepackage{grfext}
\PrependGraphicsExtensions*{.png,.PNG}
```

that will have the same effect without the need to check in `pdftex.def` for the list of extensions.

If you want also automatic conversion, you can say

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.pdf}{png}{.png}{convert #1 \OutputFile}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{%
    .png,.PNG,%
    .pdf,.PDF,%
    .jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2}
```

When `image.pdf` exists but not `image.png`, the file `image-pdf-converted-to.png` will be created and loaded in its place. Add the options you prefer between `convert` and `#1` (for example `-density 100` or something like that).

You need to call `pdflatex` with the `--shell-escape` option for this automatic conversion to work. Of course you'll comment out the `\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule` command for the final version, when only PDF files should be loaded (and switch the order of precedence in the lines below).

Comment: The solution with automatically converting between formats worked for me. It sped up the build process significantly! However, it adds a dependency to the conversion tool. For example I had to install the `convert` tool. On my Debian system, this is part of the `imagemagick` package. (`apt-get install  imagemagick`).

Answer (score 28):

A pragmatic solution would be to just have two subdirectories with illustrations, `pics` and `draftpics`, where in `draftpics` you store the low-res png's. If you use a variable like:

```
\def \picsdir {draftpics}
```

You can refer to this variable when including them using `includegraphics`:

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{\picsdir/spam}
```

At the end you only need to change the variable to get the final version.

ps I submitted hi-res png's (>300 dpi) to journals and they where accepted without any problem. And hi-res png's still load pretty quickly. So I think you might not need the pdf's...

Comment: Yes, 300dpi would be fine with me (I'm a journal graphic editor), but when I'm forced to do a conversion to bitmap myself, I do it at 600dpi usually.

Comment: What about the alternative: Either `\def\picsext{.png}` or `\def\picsext{.pdf}` combined with `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{spam\picsext}`. Is there any reason why this approach would only work as a prefix (=directory) and not as a suffix (=explicit extension)?

Answer (score 16):

Me personally, I make a poor copy of the `.pdf` graphics and use these, just when I'm finished I switch to the high-quality ones. I don't know whether there's an automated LaTeX gadget for that.

**My solution in bash (Unix systems)**
I have the full `.pdf` images stored in sub-directory `full_images`. Using the following script I convert them to preview quality:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p prev_images

for f in ./full_images/*;
do
  echo $f
  g=${f#./full_}
  convert -density 92 $f ./prev_$g
done
```

I then use one of the following commands to move the correct images to the root folder of the document:

```
cp -v ./prev_images/* .
cp -v ./full_images/* .
```

**Additional option:**

Instead of using `cp` (copy) in the last step, you can use `ln -s` (symbolic link) and save some disk space, not having the images twice. The command is one of the following:

```
ln -s full_images images
ln -s prev_images images
```

This creates a directory link, which you have to make searchable by `\includegraphics`, so you ought to put the following into your preamble:

```
\graphicspath{{images}}
```

**Additional option:**

Change the `\graphicspath` directly, i.e. having two lines with one un-commented and do not speficy the folder:

```
\graphicspath{{full_images/}}
\graphicspath{{prev_images/}}
```

Comment: just a remark as to how this could be done _transparently_. By the use of `ln` to the folders you can quick switch without having to copy anything. So simply: `ln -s full_images images` and adding that to the graphics path. `\graphicspath{{images}}`. It then only means that you can do: `ln -fs prev_images images` ot switch. Just an idea of improvement. If you don't want to add the graphics path you can `ln` the files in folder: images.

Comment: @zeroth I thought about such possibility, and I must claim that I prefer to have anything *clear* (which is not what you call *transparent*)---I don't like having files spread to multiple directories so that I have to change directory to find the true file name. I will add it as an option.

Comment: fair enough. I understand.