# Mathematica Diagrams in LyX

Tags: lyx, wolfram-mathematica

Is is possible to use diagrams from Mathematica and put them in a LyX document?

This is not just restricted to a graph or table. Also, I am wondering if one can import diagrams from wolframalpha to LyX, as wolfram is considerably easier to use than mathematica.

Comment: LaTeX can import a variety of images. See [this answer on choosing whether to include PDF or PNG in PDFLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45502/4301). So you need to export one of these types images from Mathematica which should certainly be doable.

Comment: I'm talking about LyX btw, not LaTeX but thanks!

Comment: @r.g. LyX uses LaTeX in the background, LaTeX code is generated based on your LyX file, and compiled with `pdflatex` (or `xelatex`/`lualatex`) to generate the PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because wolfram alpha (pro) can export to PDF:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/pro/
In LyX, just go to insert > graphics and then browse to find your PDF.