# Is there a way to typeout the contents of \graphicspath

Tags: graphics

First of let me admit that I've very new to the LaTeX, so this may be obvious and I just do see it, but here's my question:

I'm trying to write a set of macros to automatically downsample images... sort of like `degrade.sty`, but for images that are inserted at arbitrary sizes in the document.  What I would like to do is redefine `\includegraphics` so that this can be accomplished for existing documents.  In order to find the intended graphics file, I need to know what paths are currently in the graphics path.  Alas, I cannot figure out how to determine what those paths are.  Is this possible?

Comment: Are you just interested in seeing what it holds? For this you can use `\makeatletter\typeout{\Ginput@path}\makeatother`. The former stems doing a `\show\graphicspath`. Or do you want to do something with it programmatically?

Comment: Ugh, I feel really stupid.  I had tried just what you suggested, but decided it didn't work because I was getting an error about an undefined control sequence... It turns out that the error was the result of a debugging call to my macro - before I had ever called `\graphicspath`.  Anyway, ultimately, I'd like to provide it as an input to a script using `\write18`.

Comment: You can check whether `\Ginput@path` exists (in other words, actually test whether a call to `\graphicspath` has been made) and consequently use/act on `\Ginput@path`. I'm not sure how to do that with `\write18` though.

Comment: @Michael Have a look at [this answer of mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45502/4427) that may help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The paths for graphics - set using `\graphicspath` - is stored in `\Ginput@path` as is indicated by `\show\graphicspath` and viewing the `.log` file:

```
> \graphicspath=macro:
#1->\def \Ginput@path {#1}.
```

`\makeatletter\typeout{\Ginput@path}\makeatother` will show its contents.