# how do I print the current \graphicspath?

Tags: includegraphics

Related to
[Is there a way to typeout the contents of \graphicspath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52765/is-there-a-way-to-typeout-the-contents-of-graphicspath) .

However, I want to print the contents of `Ginput@path` to my document rather than search my log file for the contents in order to better trace out a weird bug I must have introduced somewhere. (`\showthe` or `the` even macro-ized in the prelude didn't do it.)  probably trivially easy.

Comment: It is just the same as the answer you linked to. Just leave `\typeout` out, and it will go the the stream instead of the log.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So that there's not an unanswered question lingering, making gusbr's answer explicit:

You could just expand it as normal

```
\makeatletter\Ginput@path\makeatother
```

but then you would not see the `{}` groups and any underscores in path names would cause problems. But it is just a standard TeX macro and so `\meaning` will show essentially the same string in the  as `\show` would show in the log, so

```
\makeatletter
\texttt{\meaning\Ginput@path}
\makeatother
```

Comment: my bad---I thought `makeat` could be used only in the preamble.  thx.

Comment: Minor remark: there is a typo in the second example. It should be `\makeatletter` (with an `e`)

Comment: @Icarus I made the edit—this is a community wiki answer, by the way, so anyone can edit it.