# How to deal with PDF figures

Tags: graphics, pdftex, pdf, two-column, scaling

I can insert **JPEG** figures in publications, but when it comes the time to include **PDF** figures (I prefer them for graphics because of its vectorial nature) I cannot scale them properly.

I am using `width=0.5\textwidth` because I have two-column text format, but I guess there should be a more elegant method to adjust.

I also don't find any help for `\includegraphics` inside `figure` environment commands, like

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics{image.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

Any link or help on this topic would be nice.

Comment: You can use `width=\columnwidth` rather, since `.5\textwidth` is not exactly the same as the width of the column. Also, you should avoid using the file extension (like `.pdf`). [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) defines a sequence of extensions it uses in preference order (see [Choosing whether to include PDF or PNG in PDFLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45502/5764)).

Comment: Thanks! I tried to not use .pdf, but it couldn't find the image. I will have a look to graphicx.

Comment: Another possibility is that the `.pdf` figures you are using might have some bad metadata. Try `identify -verbose myfig.pdf` and check if the image size is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use either `\linewidth` or `\columnwidth`. You can also use `\centering` before the `\includegraphics` if the image size is smaller than `\linewidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a6paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{Higgs Boson}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Image A}
\label{fig:imagea}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Image B}
\label{fig:imageb}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3-5]
\end{document}
```

### Edit 3

We usually ignore the file extension for the sake of simplicity (we can change compiler easily later).

If you use `pdflatex` then the compiler will search for JPG, PNG, or PDF. If you use `latex` then the compiler will search for EPS. For `xelatex`, it will search for JPG, PNG, PDF, and EPS.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks. Is there a good tutorial or doc webpage where I can dig on this topic? I am writing  paper and I want to manage graphics without losing much time.

Comment: @Jav_Rock: I think the theory above is sufficient unless you need more fancy image layout.

Comment: @Jav_Rock I like the inclusion of graphics in latex guide at ctan http://mirror.ctan.org/info/epslatex/english/epslatex.pdf Its the best and crisp on graphics magic