# What is the priority order when including images?

Tags: graphics

Context:
I'm currently including quite an amount of pictures into my beginner's guide. In case of , a valid image is used I created several copies in different file formats, such as `PNG`, `EPS` and `PDF`.

**Edit:** I use `pdflatex` to create my documents.

**Edit2:** Latest research found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45502/100482) to above question, which is similar to a certain degree. Hence I flag this question [duplicate].

Question in addition to above:
How does LaTeX prioritize images for inclusion?

Comment: Depends on the engine in use. Have a look at `pdftex.def`. The default will be overwritten when using `\DeclareGraphicsExtension`.

Comment: I think that egreg has a very high-score answer to a similar question about this