# \expandafter to expand macro before macro call

Tags: macros, expansion

I am trying to include an image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\ext}{.pdf}

\def\incPIC#1{ \expandafter\includegraphics{#1}}

{
\tracingmacros=1
\tracingassigns=1
\incPIC{../graphics/PerformancePlots/figureTree-P-0-10\ext}
}

\end{document}
```

The above does not work as the `\ext` is first expanded deep inside the `\includegraphics` command, I would like to expand it before the call the `\includegraphics`? what am I doing wrong. Shouldn't the `\expandafter` expand the `#1` first?

Comment: \expandafter expands the token after the next, in your case the opening brace. You would need something like `\edef\next{\noexpand\includegraphics{example-image\ext}}\next` if you want to expand a command so far away. But why are you adding the extension? pdflatex doesn't need it.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: That doesn't matter here, the code doesn't try to expand \includegraphics.

Comment: Try some pre-expansion `\def\incPIC#1{\edef\tmpa{#1}\includegraphics{\tmpa}}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Right,I read too fast

Comment: Why should you need the extension? Maybe [Choosing whether to include PDF or PNG in `pdflatex`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45498/) helps.

Comment: I switch between .pdf and .jpg with some boolean. Needed for certain convenience

Comment: @Gabriel Aren't the methods suggested in the linked answer better?

Answer (score 2):

The `\expandafter` command tries to expand *one level* the token immediately following the next one.

With your code, the tried token is `{`, which is not expandable.

Reaching the last token in the argument is impossible with `\expandafter`, because you don't know how many of them there are.

Some tricks are possible, though. The easiest one is to force complete expansion of the argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\ext}{.jpg}

\newcommand\incPIC[1]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\includegraphics{#1}%
  }\x
}

\begin{document}

\incPIC{example-image\ext}

\end{document}
```

On the other hand, the `\ext` can better go in the definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\ext}{.jpg}

\newcommand\incPIC[1]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\includegraphics{#1\ext}%
  }\x
}

\begin{document}

\incPIC{example-image}

\end{document}
```

A different trick with `xparse` and `expl3`, so it's easy to also accommodate the optional argument to `\includegraphics`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\ext}{.jpg}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \gabriel_includegraphics:nnn
 {
  \includegraphics[#2]{#3#1}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \gabriel_includegraphics:nnn { V }

\NewDocumentCommand\incPIC {O{}m}
 {
  \gabriel_includegraphics:Vnn \ext { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\incPIC{example-image}

\incPIC[width=3cm]{example-image}

\end{document}
```

See also [Choosing whether to include PDF or PNG in PDFLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45498/choosing-whether-to-include-pdf-or-png-in-pdflatex) for different strategies.